# In Python QuantLib how to identify Principal and Interest cashflows?

Tags: programming, quantlib

I am fairly new to QuantLib Python.  I have generated the following cashflows from one AmortizingFloatingBond from QuantLib Python. But I am not able to identify which ones are Interest payments and which ones are Principal; I have more than 450 bonds and it is not possible to manually look into each. Is there any tag for Principal and Interest in the QuantLib output?

```
for j, cf in enumerate(amortizingfloatbond.cashflows()):
print((j + 1), cf.date(), cf.amount())
1 October 2nd, 2020 455855.3007039195
2 October 2nd, 2020 327494.6000000001
3 October 4th, 2021 368553.92597433936
4 October 4th, 2021 327494.6
5 October 3rd, 2022 260478.18044824633
6 October 3rd, 2022 327494.6
7 October 2nd, 2023 174560.1025981066
8 October 2nd, 2023 327494.6
9 October 2nd, 2024 88260.35700473993
10 October 2nd, 2024 327494.6
```

Will really appreciate any inputs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting, something like

```
c = as_coupon(cf)
if not c.__nonzero__():
    print "principal redemption"
```

You can likewise attempt casting the `cf` to `as_fixed_rate_coupon(cf)` or to `as_floating_rate_coupon(cf)`, and if they work, then access other useful info. Also, `redemptions` is another available inspector.

Related question: [how can i see the cashflows of a specific bond created in quantlib in Python? this is the code i have, how should i change it](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/54666)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitri...this indeed works. I could cast ql.as_coupon(cf) to an object 'c' with the below code 
flds = ['ql.as_coupon']
c = []
for j, cf in list(enumerate(amortizingfloatbond.cashflows())):
    c.append({fld: eval(f"{fld}(cf)") for fld in flds})